# How to check "actual data records" residing in memory (cached data) like Shared, Resident & RAM Memory locations for a PostgreSQL process/processes?

Tags: postgresql, shared-memory

How to check "actual data records" residing in memory (cached data) like Shared Memory, Resident Memory & RAM Memory locations for a PostgreSQL process/processes? I don't want to check just size. It's mostly available in resource monitor.

I have seen many answers claiming that clearing cache data is not possible. 
if it's not possible, why?
Is it read-protected? Can the root process clear those data without killing that Postgres process? 
Means other or Postgres processes can't read that data even if we have root privileges?

Are there any inbuild functions in Postgres that can view, update or delete cached data?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgbuffercache.html but you can only _view_ the content of the shared buffers with that.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you cant clear data records in shared memory, there is no requirement for it. It caches table data and Postgres may need it.

You can not delete it because Postgres reserve whole shared memory at start.

You can view it via

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgbuffercache.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pageinspect.html

You can update it via

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgprewarm.html